# onkeypress would not work for a if the same

Tags: javascript, onkeypress

I wanted to make if you press <kbd>s</kbd> it would make the id alert you click <kbd>s</kbd>, but it was no working
[See it for your self](https://jsfiddle.net/hsoeutxr)

javascript

```js
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  if (x == 155){
    alert("You press s button");
  }
}
```

html

```html
    <body onkeypress="myFunction(event)">
       <input type="text" size="40">
       <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>https://jsfiddle.net/hsoeutxr/
```

but, it only work

```
function myFunction(event) {
  var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
  alert("You press s button");
}
```

So I would think it would be the if statement but I didn't see any problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare it with keycode 115. In your myFunction the keycode will be -

```
  function myFunction(event) {
    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
    if (x == 115) {
     alert("Hello");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes. The keyCode will be 115

Answer (score 0):

I would use typeof to check and see if x is a number because it might be a string to start with.

Comment: it is a number just look at this https://jsfiddle.net/hsoeutxr/2/